# Change the color of Photo Library button

Tags: ios, swift, alassetslibrary

I want to change the color of that "Cancel" button and also other buttons showed while selecting image from the photo library. How can I achieve this?

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = sender as? protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
sender.navigationController?.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Objective - C

Add following code in your `AppDelegate.m`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

### Swift

In `AppDelegate.swift`, in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` I put the following:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

If you want to change the text color of navigation bar then use following code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: how to use this in imagepicker?